# Inferior goods, monotonic utility and strict concavity

Tags: microeconomics, mathematical-economics

Is it possible to have an inferior good under the assumption of a utility function which is strictly monotonically increasing and strictly quasiconvex?

I do not think so, but I could not find a formal proof.

*My underlying idea is that whit an inferior good, there exist a point where the utility consuming less of one good is better and then its derivative negative at that point, moreove, I think that this behaviour would break the concavity shape.

Comment: I was reading those examples and they do not fulfill the convexity assumption.

Comment: Perhaps you have not spent enough time on the first example
$$
U(x,y) = \alpha_1 \ln(x-\gamma_x)- \alpha_2 \ln(\gamma_y - y)
$$
 which does fulfill all your conditions for $0 < \alpha_1 < \alpha_2$.

Comment: But the second derivative of U(x,y) over y is: alpha2/(gamma-y)^2 which is positive in its domain.

Comment: That is not the definition of convexity for multivariate functions. Please read the paper linked in the answer, it actually explains why convexity holds.

Answer (score 1):

I could not add images in the comments, therefore I used this method.

I think that the convexity definition does not hold for the function, since there are pairs of points that when they are conected, produce a segment which are out of the set. Because of it, the set is not convex.

Here there is an example of such situation with this function, which does not show a convex set:
[image]